# Fitnesse wiki Page Metadata is not being retained across server restarts

Tags: java, server, wiki, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am facing the following issue that I am not seeing so much discussed on forums. It would be great if someone can help out and tell me what I may be doing wrong!

**ISSUE:**

The wiki page level metadata keeps coming up as a struck through bunch of text on top of the page:

```
---
Help: Human-friendly description of the Suite
Suites: TAG1, TAG2
Suite
---
```

since the double dash symbol `--` is treated as a [strikethrough markup](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FitNesseWiki.MarkupLanguageReference.MarkupStrike), the server initially renders the whole content as stricken through!

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION:**

What seems to work is if you `Edit` the page and `Save` it while the server is running, then the page renders as expected.
But next time you start the server the problem repeats all over again!!

**MY VARIABLES**

1. The only thing I have done is gitignore the `*.zip` files!
2. I do not notice any difference at the outset any time I modify a page, so I am not sure how the wiki server is internally collecting and rendering the wiki model generated from these `*.wiki` files

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior in the past when .wiki pages were not using Linux line endings, but windows ones. We worked around this by creating a .gitattributes file stating that all wiki pages must have Linux (i.e. \n) line endings.

I thought this issue was addressed in the latest fitnesse release....

Comment: Oh, interesting.. yes, we do use an old version in our codebase, so maybe that is the reason.. Thank you :)